# Why do I get Gson builder error when starting a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, gson

I have downloaded eclipse and installed the spring suit into it.
I have written a JPA based Rest application by following one of the spring.io guides. When I try to run it as spring boot application.
I get the following error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.setLenient()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;
```

Why am I getting this error? How do I fix this error?

Here is the full output from the console.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.1.RELEASE)

2018-04-25 21:58:28.303  INFO 3574 --- [           main] .m.e.UserProfileEntityServiceApplication : Starting UserProfileEntityServiceApplication on Ajays-MBP.lan with PID 3574 (/Users/ajayamrite/workspaces/meghdoot_spring/UserProfileEntityService/target/classes started by ajayamrite in /Users/ajayamrite/workspaces/meghdoot_spring/UserProfileEntityService)
2018-04-25 21:58:28.306  INFO 3574 --- [           main] .m.e.UserProfileEntityServiceApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-04-25 21:58:28.359  INFO 3574 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@3bd40a57: startup date [Wed Apr 25 21:58:28 BST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-04-25 21:58:29.557  INFO 3574 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'httpRequestHandlerAdapter' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]]
2018-04-25 21:58:30.142  INFO 3574 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8d2d15cf] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-04-25 21:58:30.553  INFO 3574 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-04-25 21:58:30.612  INFO 3574 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-04-25 21:58:30.612  INFO 3574 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.29
2018-04-25 21:58:30.617  INFO 3574 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/ajayamrite/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
2018-04-25 21:58:30.716  INFO 3574 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-04-25 21:58:30.716  INFO 3574 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2360 ms
2018-04-25 21:58:30.826  INFO 3574 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-04-25 21:58:30.830  INFO 3574 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-25 21:58:30.831  INFO 3574 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-25 21:58:30.831  INFO 3574 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-25 21:58:30.831  INFO 3574 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-25 21:58:31.049  INFO 3574 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
Wed Apr 25 21:58:31 BST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2018-04-25 21:58:31.311  INFO 3574 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-04-25 21:58:31.373  INFO 3574 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
Wed Apr 25 21:58:31 BST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Wed Apr 25 21:58:31 BST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2018-04-25 21:58:31.443  INFO 3574 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
Wed Apr 25 21:58:31 BST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Wed Apr 25 21:58:31 BST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Wed Apr 25 21:58:31 BST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Wed Apr 25 21:58:31 BST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Wed Apr 25 21:58:31 BST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Wed Apr 25 21:58:31 BST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Wed Apr 25 21:58:31 BST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2018-04-25 21:58:31.674  INFO 3574 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.16.Final}
2018-04-25 21:58:31.675  INFO 3574 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-04-25 21:58:31.717  INFO 3574 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-04-25 21:58:31.854  INFO 3574 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2018-04-25 21:58:32.718  INFO 3574 --- [           main] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@294aba23'
2018-04-25 21:58:32.722  INFO 3574 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-04-25 21:58:33.709  INFO 3574 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-04-25 21:58:33.881  INFO 3574 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@3bd40a57: startup date [Wed Apr 25 21:58:28 BST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-04-25 21:58:33.917  WARN 3574 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2018-04-25 21:58:33.947  INFO 3574 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-04-25 21:58:33.947  INFO 3574 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-04-25 21:58:33.967  INFO 3574 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-04-25 21:58:33.967  INFO 3574 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-04-25 21:58:33.977  INFO 3574 --- [           main] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in repositoryRestExceptionHandler
2018-04-25 21:58:34.103  WARN 3574 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gsonBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/gson/GsonAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.google.gson.GsonBuilder]: Factory method 'gsonBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.setLenient()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;
2018-04-25 21:58:34.103  INFO 3574 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-04-25 21:58:34.105  INFO 3574 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-04-25 21:58:34.106  INFO 3574 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-04-25 21:58:34.109  INFO 3574 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2018-04-25 21:58:34.110  INFO 3574 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-04-25 21:58:34.120  INFO 3574 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-04-25 21:58:34.128 ERROR 3574 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gsonBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/gson/GsonAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.google.gson.GsonBuilder]: Factory method 'gsonBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.setLenient()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at co.uk.meghdoot.entity.UserProfileEntityServiceApplication.main(UserProfileEntityServiceApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.google.gson.GsonBuilder]: Factory method 'gsonBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.setLenient()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.setLenient()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration$StandardGsonBuilderCustomizer.customize(GsonAutoConfiguration.java:96) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration.lambda$gsonBuilder$0(GsonAutoConfiguration.java:49) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration.gsonBuilder(GsonAutoConfiguration.java:49) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cbe82959.CGLIB$gsonBuilder$1(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cbe82959$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6d1b6b91.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cbe82959.gsonBuilder(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.setLenient()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(MemberName.java:975) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:1000) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.java:1394) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandles.java:1750) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:477) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I would write this as a comment, but I still haven't got enough rep.

The problem must be with your dependencies. What happens here is that SpringBoot loads the [GsonAutoConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/gson/GsonAutoConfiguration.html) `@Configuration` class, which tries to call `GsonBuilder`'s `setLenient()` method. SpringBoot already has the correct gson jar set as a dependency which should automatically be included in your build; however, explicitly specifying a dependency to gson would override the dependency brought by SpringBoot. Apparently, `setLenient()` still did not exist in the version of gson that you are using.

The best you can do is either remove the explicit dependency to gson from your pom.xml (or build.gradle, or whatever else you use), or update it to match the one which is expected by the SpringBoot version you are using.

This is the most recent version of gson, in case you are using a recent version of SpringBoot:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

EDIT: it could also happen that even if you don't declare gson explicitly in your build, another one of your dependencies is using an older version of it, and it overrides the version which SpringBoot expects. In that case, instead of trying to brute-force through the problem, I would suggest to go through all your dependencies and make sure that the versions line up. Going through the dependencies and their versions listed in [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.0.1.RELEASE) might be a good idea.

Comment: It turned out that one of my dependency projects was using gson, i removed that project's dependency on gson and the problem went away.

Answer (score 30):

I faced the same problem and had to waste a lot of time trying to fix this.

The problem arises due to the version mismatch of the Gson library from existing dependencies already included in your project with that of Spring Boot's default one.

The easiest fix of this problem (that worked for me) is to replace each occurrence of the

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
```

tag with

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration.class})
```

which basically tells the Spring boot application to skip auto configuration for Gson.

This solution also applies to any other class that might create the same problem. You just need to add the name of each such conflicting class to the **exclude** attribute of **EnableAutoConfiguration**.

Comment: What features will be missing if `GsonAutoConfiguration` is skipped?

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem is related to how Spring triggers the "AutoConfiguration". In this case the "GsonAutoConfiguration" is triggered on the presence of com.google.gson.Gson.class, even if you are not using it, as it has the @ConditionalOnClass(value=Gson.class) annotation.

So the solution may be either removing the dependency that has Gson class or removing the specific "AutoConfiguration":

@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration.class})

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/gson/GsonAutoConfiguration.html

Comment: How this answer is different from already existing answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50710072/2987755 ?

Comment: It does not explain the root cause of the problem. So the solution may be either one: removing the dependency or removing the auto-configuration

Answer (score 5):

Just remove the version number the Maven dependency.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, same problem i have faced , issue is due to version mismatch between spring boot and gson....solution is remove version

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Gson dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

[refer my pom.xml snip png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPNQ3.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude GsonAutoConfiguration

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: this is the only method that takes into consideration excluding the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Just update the Gson version then it will match with the latest version of spring boot.

```
     // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson
    implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.1'
```