# How to solve Gson builder error when starting a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, gson

I am writing a new Spring Boot application and I need to use one package which has been developed by my team. This package has older Gson dependency somewhere down the hierarchy (which I could not find), therefore while running my application following error was thrown :

`NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.setLenient()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder`.

I tried to

1. [Specify the Gson dependency exclusively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3937255/3061903) in my pom, so as to enforce the latest version
2. Add the dependency in `DependencyManagement` section
3. Exclude the Gson dependency as follows :

   ```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>services</artifactId>
    <version>${version}</version>
    <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
           <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
           <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   ```

All three options did not work. finally I was able to get my application running by [excluding GsonAutoConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50710072/3061903).

Questions I am desperately trying to understand here:

1. Why the earlier options did not work
2. If I am skipping Gson AutoConfiguration, what am I losing and how can I achieve that?

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>myapp</name>


<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.boot.version>2.1.7.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    <camel.version>2.24.1</camel.version>
    <lasius.wsutils.version>3.0.37</lasius.wsutils.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.47</mysql.connector.version>
</properties>

<!--<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>-->
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


<dependencies>
    <!--Spring Boot dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>-->
    <!-- camel dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-undertow-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--being resolved from auth-->
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.9.3</version>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>services</artifactId>
        <version>${version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Comment: you can look at the AutoConfiguration implementation: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/gson/GsonAutoConfiguration.java - usually it bootsstraps a bean and some properties for your applicationContext. You can do that yourself in your configurations. But I don't understand why your option 1 did not work. Did you add it into the right module? The shortest path algorithm of maven should have resolved to that dependency. You did use a newer json version or an older one?

Comment: share your pom so we can check ...

Comment: @wemu I added the newer version as shown above in pom.xml

Comment: maybe "mvn depedency:tree" can give a hint why adding the dependency directly has no effect.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have also tried all three of those fixes with no luck. Did anyone find a solution for this?